# Anomaly forecasting algorithm for time series univariate dataset

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

I wanted to **predict/forecast anomaly** (*not detect anomaly*) for univariate dataset. 
What I really mean is i do not want to detect anomaly from existing / historical data. However I want to forecast/predict anomaly which may come in future. 
I think In Time Series forecast, it consider seasonality,trend,std error etc, hence from historical data point (even data has anomaly) TS may not predict data. Hope I am correct here.
 Can you please help to suggest python packages or algorithms or logic which will help me predict/forecast anomaly. 
Thank you